# How to write a SQL function that executes SELECT * FROM TABLE(name_function(date '01/01/2022'));?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-function

I need to write a function to which I pass a date, and in response I receive records with the same date.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(NAME VARCHAR, DATE_REG DATE);
INSERT INTO USERS(NAME, DATE_REG) VALUES ('TEST1', '01/01/2022'),('TEST2', '01/02/2022');
```

I am running a function:

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLE(name_function(date '01/01/2022'));
Expecting to receive: 'TEST1', '01/01/2022'.
```

How to write a function?

What matters to me is that the function call was "`SELECT * FROM TABLE(name_function(date '01/01/2022'));`" Script need for Oracle

Comment: Maye you can learn about `SQL` and `PostGres` in order to, as least, write an correct request prototype AND discover date parsing functions.

Comment: You have tagged Postgres and Oracle, which are you using?

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` and  `INSERT` statements are not valid in Oracle. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fbecdc4d28cbeb98c484de2635496d9f)

Comment: Why do you need a function? Just query `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE DATE_REG =  '01/01/2022'` (where exact syntax depends whether you have Oracle or PostGres)

Comment: Function to select from a table `table_name` is `select * from table_name where ...`. Please, do not develop convoluted solutions, someone will have to support them. But to answer the question: Oracle have no generic types, you cannot create function to return anything from anywhere, function output has to be structured

Answer (score 1):

1. To correct your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO USERS(NAME, DATE_REG) VALUES ('TEST1', TO_DATE('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd'));

SELECT NAME, DATE_REG FROM USERS 
WHERE 
DATE_REG = TO_DATE('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

2. Normal function return you one value, you can consider create procedure that create some results table or function (Return a «table» from a function)

You can try:
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/PL-SQL/collection-types/return-table-from-function/index

So you should take your date as parameter then, get results from select and transform results to result table and return from function